# Django Reverse for ' ' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: html, error-handling, python-3.10, django-errors, django-4.0

I have a problem while using Django. I was trying to create a learning_log web application from my book and came across this error: NoReverseMatch at /edit_entry/8/
Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topics/(?P<topic_id>[0-9]+)/\Z']. It said it was because of this line in my edit_entry.html file: `p><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>` but I checked my entire project and couldn't find the reason,
Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
    path('new_topic/', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    path('new_entry/<int:topic_id>/', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
    path('edit_entry/<int:entry_id>/', views.edit_entry, name='edit_entry'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Topic, Entry
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm
def index(request):
    """The home page for Learning Log."""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')
def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries':entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new topic."""
    if request.method !='POST':
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topics')

    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    """Edit and existing entry."""
    entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id)
    topic = entry.topic

    if request.method !='POST':
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic.id)

   context = {'entry': entry, 'topic': topic, 'form': form}
   return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html')
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific about a learned topic."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return f"{self.text[:50]}..."
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Topic, Entry

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

base.html:

```
<p>
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a>
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a>
</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

topics.html:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Topics</p>

  <ul>
    {% for topic in topics %}
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
      </li>
    {% empty %}
      <li>No topics have been added yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}">Add a new topic</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

new_topic.html:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Add a new topic:</p>

  <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">Add topic</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

new_entry.html:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>

  <p>Add a new entry:</p>
  <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name='submit'>Add entry</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

topic.html:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Topic: {{ topic }}</p>

  <p>Entries:</p>
  <p>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}">Add new entry</a>
  <ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
      <li>
        <p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
        <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
        <p>
          <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_entry' entry.id %}">Edit entry</a>
        </p>
      </li>
    {% empty %}
      <li>There are no entries for this topic yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

edit_entry.html:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>

  <p>Edit entry</p>

  <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_entry' entry.id %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">Save changes</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Learning Log helps you keep track of what you've learned.</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

and that is literally everything I checked and I can't seem to find the error, please help me find the error and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

In views.py, on the `edit_entry` function, pass `context` to the render method.

On the very last line of the `edit_entry` function, in the `views.py` file, add the `context` to the arguments you are passing to the returned `render` method.

```
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    """Edit and existing entry."""
    entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id)
    topic = entry.topic

    if request.method !='POST':
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic.id)

   context = {'entry': entry, 'topic': topic, 'form': form}
   return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html')
```

Correct the last line as follows, by adding `context`. This is so can you can use the `entry`, `topic`, and `form` that you defined in the `context` in the html template.

```
   return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html', context)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I'm really new to django and I don't know what a render method is, so could you please kindly tell me how to do that? Thanks!